# Sampling spatial data frame in R

Tags: r, spatial

I want to sample a large SpatialDataFrame (+50000 elements) in order to facilitate my developpement.
However sample function seems not to work with spatialdataframe, and the spsample function from sp package have a different purpose.
Anyone have yet faced this problem?

Comment: Why don't you just sample the indices, and then use those to split your dataframe? E.g. my_indices <- sample(1:50000, replace=FALSE), and then subset the dataframe df[my_indices,]. I have worked with sp dataframes before, and this should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the tour, the help center and the how to ask a good question sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Faced similar recently; used dplyr.    
`my_df <- dplyr::sample_n(sp_obj@data, 1000)`    
`test <- sp_obj[sp_obj$var %in% my_df$var, ]`    
`plot(test)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried several solutions, and found one based on your idea *Esben Eickhardt* :

```
sample <- spdataframe[sample(1:length(spdataframe), 1000),]
```

Sadly sample_n from dplyr is not working with spatialdataframe, and thee solution you proposed *Anthony Simon Mielniczuk* is not working (sampling empty dataframe).